# I need regular expression in java to get text(along with first date) between dates

Tags: java, regex

I need regular expression in java to get text(along with start date) between dates

note:content in multiple lines

my text is in multiple lines like below:

> 05/22/2014 03:22:39.288 ffff gggg kkkkkk lllllll ssss kbhfg kjjkfjkne
>   kjjj
>
> jhgdj6 saghjajdg hjhjdsjsa fkejfkw
>
> 05/22/2014 03:22:39.288 oooooo ppppp qqqq rrrrrr sss hkwhfwe fewhjgjw
>   hew jggjg khj
>
> h gjfgw jgjs gad6jgj hdasggs hjhjwefj ewhrew
>
> 05/22/2014 03:22:39.378 mmmmmm nnn oooo
>
> dsa6j gdsaja sgdjhs agj kbewbf hwe khhwejh

if i have input:

**05/22/2014 03:22:39.288 ffff gggg kkkkkk  05/22/2014 lllllll**

**ssss kbhfg kjjkfjkne kjjj jhhjd jjhg jhhjgj**

it should not highlight upto **alone date** it must highlight in between **date time** content along with start date time.

Comment: i tried (?=\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3} )(.*?)(?=(?: \\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}|$)) this but it only get if entire content in single line.i need content in multiple lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
(?s)[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}.*?(?=\s*[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}|$)
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xR9sB7).

Comment: i need start date with content upto end date excluded end date.the demo not gives results

Comment: The demo gives you 3 (Three) matches. (Look at the color changing.) Isn't that what you want? Yes, from the start date to the next part before a date. If not, please edit your post to show exactly your desired matches (all of them). Thanks! :)

Comment: yes it gives me but i need hit only datetime together in between if i have date it should not give hit

Comment: Don't understand. Please show your expected output, otherwise I give up. Edit your question. Show it.

Comment: i have updated question can you please respond me,thank you

Comment: Glad it works, thanks! See you next time. :)